# How to make wordpress default search to woocommerce search

Tags: search, woocommerce-offtopic

I use the get_product_search_form filter in replace of get_search_form, and I did changes in function.php file. But still I am not getting the solutions, Can anybody help me here Please.

If I search any products then I am getting such type of output: [https://www.hickorydickorybox.com/?s=air+hover](https://www.hickorydickorybox.com/?s=air%20hover)

But I want this: [https://www.hickorydickorybox.com/?s=air+hover&post_type=product](https://www.hickorydickorybox.com/?s=air%20hover&post_type=product)

Comment: modify the `wp_query` written on search.php

Comment: We dont write WP_Query in search.php . Search.php automatically populates the latest 10 posts or page or CPT and displays it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'pre_get_posts' filter hook and change the search query.

```
function wpse_search_filter( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('product') ); // setting post type as product (for woocommerce only)
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpse_search_filter');
```